# How can i rename several file names at once ? starting from - character till the end

Tags: mac, macos

I'm going to rename thouthands of files at once. They have all the same '-' char. I have to delete(or replace) everything from that char till the end. How can I do that? Please help me...

File names ex:

```
AG - Antigua and Barbuda.svg
AU - Australia.svg
BG - Bulgaria.svg
```

I'm going to delete all strings after the country codes(like AG).

All files are in one folder.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add a few of those filenames, and the expected result? Also, are all these files in the same directory, or spread across several?

Comment: @nohillside I have edited

Comment: So you want to rename `AU - Australia.svg` to `AU`, without the suffix?

Comment: yes that is right. for all files in the folder

Comment: Is it possible that some of the files have the same characters before `-` but different characters after it? If so, how do you wish to rename, for example, `AU - Australia.svg` and `AU - Sidney.svg`? I am asking because macOS will not allow two files with exactly the same name to exist in the same folder. Do you wish to rename them for example as `AU 1`and `AU 2` or how?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming somewhat sane filenames, no duplicate country codes and only one occurence of `-`  in each name:

- Open Terminal
- Type `cd`  followed by a space
- Drag&drop the folder containing the files into the Terminal window
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `for i in *" - "*.svg; do mv "$i" "${i% - *}"; done` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I'm getting permission denied message.
like: zsh: permission denied: filePath

Comment: I think one needs to think carefully before using this script because if there is more than one file with the same characters before `-`, this will keep only one of those files as renamed and delete the rest.

Comment: I have to go to the file with cd ... and run the script that you specified. It works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try [NameChanger](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/), a free utility for macOS. I have been using it for a while and have been quite happy with it.

In your case, I suggest using the Regular Expression function in NameChanger. After installing and launching the app, select the files you wish to rename in the Finder and drag and drop them into NameChanger or right-click on them and select "Rename with NameChanger" in the context menu. You can also select the files you wish to rename through NameChanger's Add button.

Then, select the Regular Expression function through the drop-down menu in the middle at the top of the app. Put exactly the following in the Original Text field (the one on the left):

`([A-Z]{2}) - .*\.svg`

and the next one in the New Text field (the one to the right) as shown below:

`$1`

[image]

Once you do these, check out the preview in the Renamed Filename column. A new file name appears in Renamed Filename column for a file only if its name is to be changed based on the instructions you just put in. If the two or more the files to be renamed have the same new name, the latter names are automatically added a number starting with `1` by the app.

If you are happy with the preview in the Renamed Filename column, click on the Rename button at the top right in NameChanger and you are done!

Before making changes to a lot of files, I suggest making copies a few of them under a new folder and trying NameChanger on those extra copies. Once you are happy with the results and comfortable using the app, you can go and change the names of the original files. Finally, while the learning curve is a bit steep, see this [Regular Expressions Tutorial](https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/) if you wish to learn more about regular expressions (regex); there are many other freely available regex tutorials on the Internet.